# Changing leaderboard to TieRankingLeaderboard

Tags: ruby, leaderboard

I'm using the [leaderboard gem](https://github.com/agoragames/leaderboard) and it says that there are three different types of leaderboard (Default, TieRankingLeaderboard and CompetitionRankingLeaderboard) but it doesn't make it clear where you can change the type of leaderboard.

I have this in my boards.rb:

```
module Boards
  DEFAULT_BOARD = 'percentage_lb'

  def self.default_leaderboard
    Leaderboard.new(
    DEFAULT_BOARD,
    default_options,
    redis_connnection: Redis.current
    )
  end

  def self.default_options
    Leaderboard::DEFAULT_OPTIONS.merge(
    page_size: 10
    )
  end

  class Base
    def leaderboard
      @leaderboard ||= Boards.default_leaderboard
    end

    def member_exists?(name)
      leaderboard.check_member?(name)
    end
  end
end
```

and I've tried adding TieRankingLeaderboard in several different places but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else comes across this issue, it took me ages to figure out but I fixed it by putting this into the application.rb:

```
require 'tie_ranking_leaderboard'
```

And then putting `TieRankingLeaderboard.new` instead of `Leaderboard.new`

Comment: You saved my life here. I spent 5 hours already figuring this out!!